# Springboot application.properites not read

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I've developed a springboot application with Maven in Eclipse. The class annotated with @SpringBootApplication reads the application.properties inside src/main/resources. Inside Eclipse everything works fine. 
Using Maven I've generated a fat jar, this is the plugin I'm using:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In the target folder 2 jars are generated, one named fatjar-exec.jar and the other fatjar.jar. When I run the command java -jar fatjar-exec.jar an exception is thrown since the application is not able to read the application.properties file. 
I have also unzipped the jar and correctly the applciation.properties is located under BOOT-INF/classes folder. Any hints?

Comment: try adding the following annotation in the main class:
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value="classpath:application.properties")

})

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help

Comment: Try with add version   `<plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>`

Answer (score 2):

Please compare the contents of generated fatjars.
The regular one (without exec) has only one copy of springboot classes,
while the one generated with the clasifier has two.

- one under `/org/springframework/boot/loader` (expected)
- second under `/BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/boot/loader`

Probably the order of classpath search causes the file from the unexpected location to be picked up, and it cannot find the properties in `/BOOT-INF/classes`

IMHO the simplest version works best:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Check [Custom repackage classifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html) for details how to configure maven if you want to keep the origial file (you were missing `<id>repackage</id>`).

Comment: First part is correct, I've tried also without the executions tag, but the problem is still the same

Comment: I tried it with a project generated with Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io/). It works out of the box. Maybe having a minimal sample that works correctly will help you.

Comment: I've tried the project you suggested and another project with spring I am developing and both work correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me fine too.
My POM.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

mvn package -DskipTests

java -jar xxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar